# Global Variable with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, this

I am trying to make the coding a lot easier for me and so I assigned a global.

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
var parentModule = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

And I use these through out my code to make $(this) a lot easier and save on all the parents. Though $(this) would technically be universal being within that certain event (click,hover, and so forth)

Is there a way of actually doing this as I believe it is not possible like the way I write it.
maybe a function or something?

```
var parent, parentModule = null;
  function getParents(e){
  parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".module");
  parentModule = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".module").parent();
}
$(close).on('click',function (e) {
 getParents(e);
if (parentModule.hasClass('open')) {
        var a = ReadCookie('ToHide');
        if (a.split(",").length === 0) {
            KillCookie('ToHide');
            var b = "#"+parent.attr("id") + " #"+parentModule.attr("id");
            SetCookie('ToHide', b, 100);
        } else {
           var d = a + "," + "#"+ parent.attr("id") + " #"+parentModule.attr("id");
            KillCookie('ToHide');
            SetCookie('ToHide',d, 100);
        }
        if(animate===true){
        parentModule.fadeOut(function(){
        checkIfVisible();
});
```

Comment: Tip: Don't do this `parent().parent().parent().parent()`, check http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: cache your `$(this)` selector and then use `.closest(someClass)` to get the ancestor you are looking for

Comment: Exactly use $(this).closest('whicheverparent'). This will make maintenance and readability better, and event if you insert another hierarchy inside the intented parent you closest will still work, but not parent().parent().. etc

Comment: I think what you are trying to do would be a lot easier if you use the `eq(n)` jQuery operator in this way:

    `var parent = $(this).parents().eq(2)`
    `var parentModule = $(this).parents().eq(3)`

Comment: Can you post the relative markup as well?

Comment: @JudeDuran http://jsbin.com/uvenum/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the values of those global variables using a function, try this:

```
var parent, parentModule = null;
function getParents(e){
  parent = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".yourParentSelector");
  parentModule = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".yourParentModuleSelector");
}

$("button").click(function(e){
  getParents(e);
  //do whatever you want with parent and parentModule variables
});
```

Use `closest()` instead of `parent()`

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eAHnM/2/)**

Comment: Ok this looks nice, could I do this for `parentModule` `$(e.currentTarget).closest('element').parent()` ? As the parent has an idea, and there are two I need, #left and #right so using the parent would be easier

Comment: If the `parentModule` differs from case to case basis, then **YES** you can do that. But if you're sure what the `prentModule` is OR it has a *general class*, you can just directly put it in the `closest()` selector.

Comment: well that is the issue it doesn't have a class. Only id, and by gaining parent() I can then get the specific id. I will try this out, if it works upvote and I'll select this as my answer

Comment: This may look nice until you'll try to execute getParents() in multiple event handlers in the nearly same time. It's quite easy actually. Then you'll catch some nasty bugs which you would have hard time getting rid of.

Comment: like what? I already rewrote it to add this function. Please explain more

Comment: I think he's saying if you use this function at the same time. Like bind it in click and  then in focus event. It will fire twice and MIGHT get different values. Soultion: **then dont do that**. Just bind this to the eventlistener where you'll need it.

Comment: I used this, and I am getting nothing. It just isn't working. I added e to the function of all events. As well as the getParents(e) right after. I only have click events nothing else.

Comment: @JudeDuran http://jsbin.com/uvenum/2/edit  full code. 3 warnings of mixed spaces.

Comment: Alright so I figured out, that the problem was I had parentModule and parent backwards on my behalf. I just need to fix the rest and check it out ;)

Comment: OK just let me know if there's a conflict with the function..;]

Comment: works great. Just had one small problem with one forum version and its phpbb2 so who cares :D